# Copying double value from a column of a table into another string column with fixed lenth pattern in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql and came across a problem.

I have a column name price(Double) and i want to create a new column in the same table of datatype String and wants to copy the price into new column for all rows present in the table
with fixed length pattern.

example i want to do the following

```
  Price(double)      newcolumn(String)
     12                      00012
      1                      00001
      0                      00000
```

please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: How would you deal with decimal points? Or the price is always an int represented in a double?

Comment: the price is always an int represented in a double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could work:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET newcolumn = LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(Price,0),',',''),5,'0')
```

The `FORMAT` function converts the double into a string with 0 decimals and here is the [api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format).
The `FORMAT` introduces commas to separate thousands so we need to use `REPLACE` to get rid of those and here is the [api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).
The `LPAD` function left pads with the `'0'` and here is the [api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)